# Return Granite validation errors as JSON

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

I have a Granite `User` model with some validations. When someone makes a `POST` request to `users/new`, I'd like to return the validation errors (if any) as JSON. Currently, I have:

```
if user.errors.size > 0
  halt env, status_code: 500, response: user.errors.to_json
end
```

But when I try to compile, I get:

```
in /usr/local/Cellar/crystal/0.26.1/src/json/to_json.cr:66: no overload 
matches 'Granite::Error#to_json' with type JSON::Builder
Overloads are:
- Object#to_json(io : IO)
- Object#to_json()

  each &.to_json(json)
         ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that `User#errors` is an `Array(Granite::Error)`, i.e. an `Array` holding `Granite::Error`s. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like `Granite::Error` implements the `to_json(JSON::Builder)` method (i.e. the method `to_json` taking a parameter of type `JSON::Builder`), which `Array#to_json` relies on (that snippet you see there is from the implementation of `Array#to_json` which you can [view on GitHub](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/0004179c9576c89d14e617423828af6f31e6d7a1/src/json/to_json.cr).).

I'd recommend building the JSON yourself using [`JSON.build`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/JSON.html#build%28indent%3Dnil%2C%26block%29-class-method). This has the added side-effect of keeping the JSON that you respond with (which I imagine is being consumed by some client) is entirely in *your* control. If the developers of Granite were to change how they encode `Granite::Error`s in JSON and you were using their `to_json` method, the change wouldn't raise anything at compile time.

As a side-note, I'd recommend against using a status code of 500 to denote a validation error, as that is typically reserved for unexpected errors internal to your server. A 4xx error (e.g. 400 - Bad Request) would be more appropriate. As a second side-note, it would be more RESTful to have the `POST` be made to the `/users` endpoint, as opposed to `/users/new`.

With these changes, here would be the resulting snippet:

```ruby
if user.errors.size > 0
  errors_as_json = JSON.build do |json|
    json.array do
      user.errors.each do |error|
        json.string error.to_s
      end
    end
  end
  halt env, status_code: 400, response: errors_as_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I haven't had time to work on that project in a little while. Once I do, if your solution works, I'll accept it as the answer.